# How to convert from decimal coordinate (1,1) to Excel Style Coordinate A1 in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, data-conversion

I have an API that outputs the coordinates for excel in decimal format(1,1). I am trying to convert from decimal coordinates for excel like (1,1) to be converted to A1 in excel, since I have another API, to which I am trying to provide the coordinates that only takes in that input of classic excel style coordinates, A1.

I wish to be able to take the output from the API **(100,45)** and convert it to **CW45** to be input in the other API

How can I accomplish this?

I do know how to convert to the letter when the number is BY ITSELF with:

```
function Convert-ToLetters ([parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][int] $value)  {
$currVal = $value;
$returnVal = '';
while ($currVal -ge 26) {
    $returnVal = [char](($currVal) % 26 + 65) + $returnVal;
    $currVal =  [int][math]::Floor($currVal / 26)
}
$returnVal = [char](($currVal) + 64) + $returnVal;

return $returnVal
}
```

But i cant figure out how just do the first number in (1,2) and ignore the second number and combine it together in the end for it to be A2 instead of (A,2)

Thanks

---

---

Thanks to @MikeGaruccio for his help

the final is

```
$oldCoordinates = @(1,1)
$newCoordinates = "$(Convert-ToLetters $oldCoordinates[0])$($oldCoordinates[1])"
```

and if I have a input which I have turned into a variable like **$boo = (x,y)**  with x and y representing any set of numbers, not the letters themselves; it's as simple as the following:

```
$oldCoordinates = @($boo)
$newCoordinates = "$(Convert-ToLetters $oldCoordinates[0])$($oldCoordinates[1])"
```

Comment: So you call that function like so: `Convert-ToLetters 1.2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple lookup table will work if you are dealing with input files that have a relatively small and known number of columns.

```
$arr = @{
  A = 1
  B = 2
  C = 3
  (etc)
}

$oldCoordinates = @(1,1)
$newCoordinates = "$($arr[$oldCoordinates[0]])$($oldCoordiantes[1])"
```

If you go much beyond 10 columns or so $arr becomes a bit of a pain to generate though so this may not be ideal for large sheets.

**Edit**

Ahh you took care of the hard part, separating them out is quite easy, your just building a string and populating it with the two values you need, the converted letters for the column and the existing row number.  leaving the solution above for reference in case anyone needs it.

```
$oldCoordinates = @(1,1)
$newCoordinates = "$(Convert-ToLetters $oldCoordinates[0])$($oldCoordinates[1])"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You're awesome

Comment: what output do you get from the first API? Is it a string or array?

Comment: ...its fine... i was just having a massive brainfart...at overcomplicating something very simple... just needed to insert the variable in the right place..... Thanks though